# Scala Future.fold gone?

Tags: scala

I have seen Scala code examples in quite recent books (2014+) that use methods such as `Future.successful`, `Future.reduce`, `Future.fold`... but I cannot find them in the scaladoc:

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/dispatch/Future.html

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future

Also, what is the difference between `scala.concurrent.Future` and `akka.dispatch.Future`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching in the wrong place: those methods belong to the companion object of `Future` and they are still there:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future$

And `akka.dispatch.Future` was moved into Scala long ago. See [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html).

Comment: Nice :) Two different things with the same name :)

Comment: The linked doc doesn't take me to the appropriate documents anymore, but this one worked: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html